# How is Java Timer implemented by the computer?

Tags: java, timer

The articles on the site related to Timer talk about how to use Timer to program.

I ask a different question.
How does Java perform Timer method?

Since it is said to avoid time-consuming work by not to use while loop to check whether the current time is the required time point, I think Timer is not implemented simply by using while loop to continuously checking and comparing the current time to the desired time point.

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Go to the [OpenJDK source repo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/); 2. Look for answer; 3. ???; 4. Profit.

Comment: Profit? What does it mean?

Comment: It is a reference to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tO5sxLapAts

Comment: Interesting. But I am so dumb that I don't get it. :)(

Answer (score 3):

> I think Timer is not implemented simply by using while loop to continuously
>   checking and comparing the current time to the desired time point.

**YES, IT IS.** The only optimization is; it is using priority queue based on nextExecutionTime for tasks.

JavaDoc states

> Timer object is a single background thread that is used to
>   execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should
>   complete quickly.  If a timer task takes excessive time to complete,
>   it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread.  This can, in turn, delay
>   the execution of subsequent tasks

Timer class contains

1. `TaskQueue` which is a priority queue of TimerTasks, ordered on nextExecutionTime.
2. `TimerThread(queue)` the timer's task execution thread, which waits (`queue.wait()`) for tasks on the timer queue.

`TimerThread` has `private void mainLoop() {` 
 where continuous `while(true)` will keep checking the tasks by comparing `nextExecutionTime` with `currentTimeMillis`

```
                    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    executionTime = task.nextExecutionTime;
                    if (taskFired = (executionTime<=currentTime)) {
```

and if it reaches then calling

```
            if (taskFired)  // Task fired; run it, holding no locks
                task.run();
```

Comment: if Java Timer uses loop, then how accurate the timer is?

Answer (score 2):

According for the javadoc

> This class does not offer real-time guarantees: it schedules tasks
>   using the Object.wait(long) method.

If you look in the code you will find a method called main loop. The first couple of lines are copied below.

```
private void mainLoop() {
    while (true) {
        try {
```

And... it uses a while loop inside of it along with `Object.wait()` to do the waiting.

Comment: Thanks. Then how is Object.wait() implemented? I still assume it does not use while loop.

Comment: `Object.wait()` is a "built-in" method which is implemented in native code, not in Java. It makes use of the underlying operating system's facilities for suspending execution of a thread (so the OS' scheduler will not give it any CPU time).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I thought. I looked into OS to look for the answer. Then how does the operating system implement it without cost of CPU time? Any link so that I could find reference?

Comment: @user1914692 As far as Java goes, the answer is that you shouldn't care. The API docs & the JLS document the behavior you can expect, I doubt the JLS goes into any specifics about implementation too. Now, if you really want to know how the OS itself implements this -- for a vaguer description, you should get a book on OS concepts / design, like [this one](http://os-book.com/). If after that you really, **really** want to know, check the OpenJDK code & dig through the kernel code, they're both open. I suspect you'll see `pthread` magic, but no idea really.

Comment: Thanks. I also heard that although Timer, or Thread.sleep, does not consume CPU time, they are not accurate. Is it correct? If I want to accurately control time points of multiple threads and events, where should I find detailed references?